# Redis doesn't update dump.rdb any more

Tags: redis

I've been using Redis on a windows server for last 10 months without any issue but this morning I checked my website and saw that it's completely empty!!!

After a few minutes of investigation I realised that Redis database was empty???

Luckily I use redis as a caching solution so I still have all data in MS SQL database and I've managed to recover content of my website.

But I realised that redis has stopped saving data into dump.rdb. The last time file was updated 20.11.2015 at 11:35.

Redis config file has set

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

and by just reloading all from MS SQL this morning I had more than 15.000 writes. So the file should be updated, right?

I run redis-check-dump dump.rdb and as result got:

```
Processed 7924 valid opcodes
```

I even run manually SAVE command and as result got:

```
OK <2.12>
```

But the file size and update date of dump.rdb is the same 20.11.2015

I just want to highlight that between 20.11.2015 and today I haven't changed anything in redis configuration or restarted the server

Any idea?

Comment: You might want to check whatever the Windows equivalent of syslog is (event log maybe?!) to see if an error has been written during save

Comment: I tried but no luck, noting in the the even log

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer but at least I've managed to make Redis to start dumping data to disk.

Using console I set a new dbfilename name and now Redis is again dumping data data to disk.

It would be great if someone has a clue why it had stopped duping data to original dump file